# Returning a string from a piecewise function

Tags: functions, piecewise

I need to define a function that behaves as a piecewise function, but will return a string instead of a value. Part of the function that I have written is provided below. The full function continues for several additional lines with additional values of `od` and different values for the slot positions. The line of code for `od == 1.050` illustrates where I need to return the string `"XXS"`.  The values `od` and `tol` are input values to the notebook. The notebook calculates `T`.

```
pipeschedule[od_, tol_, T_] := 
  Which[
    od == 0.405, Piecewise[{{#1, T <= (tol*#2)}, {#3, (tol*#2) < T <= (tol*#4)}}, "___"]&[40, 0.068, 80, 0.095],
    od == 0.540, Piecewise[{{#1, T <= (tol*#2)}, {#3, (tol*#2) < T <= (tol*#4)}}, "___"]&[40, 0.088, 80, 0.119],
    od == 0.675, Piecewise[{{#1, T <= (tol*#2)}, {#3, (tol*#2) < T <= (tol*#4)}}, "___"]&[40, 0.091, 80, 0.126],
    od == 0.840, Piecewise[{{#1, T <= (tol*#2)}, {#3, (tol*#2) < T <= (tol*#4)}}, "___"]&[40, 0.091, 80, 0.126],
    od == 1.050, Piecewise[{{#1, T <= (tol*#2)}, {#3, (tol*#2) < T <= (tol*#4)}, {#5, (tol*#4) < T <= (tol*#6)}, {#7, (tol*#6) < T <= (tol*#8)}}, "___"]&[40,0.109, 80, 0.147, 160, 0.188, "XXS", 0.294]]]
```

Is there a different function that will accept strings?

Comment: Hi bangeo, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Can you give an example of a cases where you have strings? It's hard to envision what you mean to do with the function. In any case, it sounds like you're looking for `If` or `Switch`?

Comment: Thanks for the help and example of where I have strings from the larges code is  pipeschedule[od_, tol_, T_] := Which[  od == 0.405,  Piecewise[{{#1, T <= (tol*#2)}, {#3, (tol*#2) < T <= (tol*#4)}},  "___"] &[40, 0.068, 80, 0.095],
od == 1.050,  Piecewise[{{#1, T <= (tol*#2)}, {#3, (tol*#2) < T <= (tol*#4)}, {#5, (tol*#4) < T <= (tol*#6)}, {#7, (tol*#6) < T <= (tol*#8)}}, "___"] &[40,
    0.109, 80, 0.147, 160, 0.188, "XXS", 0.294]].  In the final case "XXS" is the string. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information to it inside ``` characters so that it's formatted correctly (see formatting help near the edit box) - comments aren't useful for this type of thing!

Comment: I think I'm still not understanding what it is that you're trying to do. If I input `pipeschedule[1.050, 0.1, 0.02]`, I get `XXS` as the result from your code. Is that not what you want to get? If you want to avoid using `Piecewise`, it still looks to me like `Which` should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Interesting that I do not get the same result.  I will revise the question to show the result I receive.  For pipeschedule[1.050, 1, .2], I get

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Interesting that I do not get the same result.  I will revise the question to show the result I receive.  For pipeschedule[1.050, 1, .2], I get 10ST<=0.083
40S 0.083<T<=0.113
80S 0.113< T<=0.154
160 0.154<T<=0.219
XXS 0.219<T<=0.308  Don't yet understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `Which` for these sorts of things, but it might depend on exactly what your needs are.

```
f[w_, x_, y_, z_] := Which[
   tmin <= x tol,
   w,
   x tol < tmin <= z tol,
   y]
f[40, 0.1, 80, 0.3]
```

You can also set it up as a pure function like you have in your question:

```
Which[
    tmin <= #2 tol,
    #1,
    #2 tol < tmin <= #4 tol,
    #3]&[40, 0.1, 80, 0.3]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I see I need to provide additional detail.

Comment: Please see above comment for additional information.  Thanks again